# NavigationView in TabView crashes app when pop back

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have `TabView` which has `SearchView` view with `List` in it. When I click to item in list to present another view, my app stops and not respond to any touches.

**MainView**

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
           NavigationView{
              SearchView().navigationBarTitle(Text(""))
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
           }.tabItem({
               Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
               Text("Search")
           })
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchView**

```
struct SearchView: View {

    let items = ["1","2", "3"]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id : \.self) { item in 
             NavigationLink(destination : ItemsView()){
                 Text(item)
             }

        }
    }
}
```

**ItemsView**

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Text("ItemsView")
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version Xcode is this? the latest one shows no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed a bit the SearchView class and it does not crash:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemsView()) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```